# Visual Studio 2013 RDLC wrong page size

Tags: visual-studio-2013, size, rdlc, reportviewer, page-size

I have a problem with the settings of Page Size in **Visual Studio 2013** with `RDLC`.

When I set the size of an **A4** sheet of my report, following the measuring grid (set in cm) it gives me **Visual Studio** seems to coincide with the real size of the page.

When I do the print preview doing debugging of my program displays multiple pages because the content does not fit and leaves the size, despite being respected.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure width of the Report's Body Property is less than or equal to the Paper size you select.
For A4 size the width is 11.69 inch, so go to the report's body property by pressing F4 and define its width according to your page size.

See for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrisbal/2006/08/10/the-every-other-page-is-blank-feature/

Answer (score 1):

I see its old post, but maybe somebody need it.
I had same problem using **Visual Studio 2015** on **Windows 10** and it turns out it was problem with Windows 10 Scaling option in Display Settings, not with my code or design.

Try right click on Desktop, Display Settings, Scaling and layout, Change size of text, apps and other items, set it to 100%.